# VB net DataGridView inside Panel inside TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tablelayoutpanel, ctype

I'm trying to access DataGridView inside Panel which is inside a TableLayoutPanel that is located in **Form3** from **Form5**. I tried the following:

```
    ' this code from Form5
    Dim testPanel As Panel = CType(Form3.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls("Panel1"), Panel)
    Dim testdgv As DataGridView = CType(testPanel.Controls("topics_and_schedule_DGview"), DataGridView)
    ' instead of CType I tried DirectCast and TryCast

    MsgBox(testdgv.Parent.Name)  --> Display "Panel1"
    MsgBox(testdgv.Name)   --> Display "topics_and_schedule_DGView"
    MsgBox(testdgv.Columns.Count) --> Display 0 (should be 2)

    MsgBox(Form3.topics_and_schedule_DGview.Parent.Name) --> Display "Panel1"
    MsgBox(Form3.topics_and_schedule_DGview.Columns.Count) --> Display 0 (should be 2)
```

When I write the following:

```
Form3.TableLayoutPanel1.Panel1.topics_and_schedule_DGview
```

It complains during design view saying "Panel1 is not member of TableLayoutPanel

and when I run the following:

```
Dim cControl As Control
    For Each cControl In testPanel.Controls
        If cControl.Name = "topics_and_schedule_DGview" Then
            Dim ss As DataGridView = cControl
            MsgBox(ss.Columns.Count)   ---> Display 0 
        End If
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + " -- " & cControl.Name

    Next cControl
```

I was able to see the desired DataGridView, but was getting zero as columns count!!

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: you do not need to reference every container to use your DGV.  just use `DataGridView1` or whatever name you gave it

Comment: Why don't you access it like so: `Form3.topics_and_schedule_DGview`

Comment: I used Form3.topics_and_schedule_DGview .. but as you see above, it was not able to get the correct number of columns in the field!